# EntityUtils toString takes too long on big responses

Tags: java, http, post

The following code :

```
//
// Define HTTP Post and content
//
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
ByteArrayEntity be = new ByteArrayEntity(strPostData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
httppost.setEntity(be);
//
// Define HTTP Client
// 
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams httpParameters = httpclient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10 * 1000);
//      
// Sets the default socket timeout
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
//
int timeoutSocket = 10000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
//      
// This line takes too long on big responses
//
String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

The last line (EntityUtils.toString) takes too long when my response contains a large amount of Bytes.

I'm using HTTP Post to retrieve PDF files **(up to 500 Kb)** and it may take 1 or 2 seconds on each request, which is too much.

*EDIT For Information : The PDF file is base 64 encoded and wrapped into XML Tag (the string is parsed after reception).*

Is there any way to get my String response a faster way ?

EDIT 2 : in order to know how much time took my EntityUtils.toString, I made a method :

```
public static void logger(String header, String content) {
    Date dateActualLog = new Date();
    long milliseconds = (dateActualLog.getTime() - dateLastLog.getTime());
    Log.d(header, String.valueOf(milliseconds) + " => " + content);
    dateLastLog = dateActualLog;
}
```

(fyi : dateLastLog is a static variable)

I modified the above code like this :

```
//      
// This line takes too long on big responses
//
logger(TAG, "toString ...");
String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
logger(TAG, "toString OK");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do that.  You cannot store arbitrary binary data in a string.

Comment: My PDF files are all base 64 encoded and wrapped into XML tags, sorry, I did not mention that, I edit my question right now.

Comment: Are you sure that it's `toString()` to blame? What if you try to read the response body as `InputStream`?

Comment: I added EDIT2 for further information, I tried as an inputStream and it didnt change the treatment time issue.

Comment: so, if i understand correctly, it takes a long time to download the file.  so, what's your question?

Comment: Is there another library or another method to get my String result from an http post Request ? The same code section adapted for iOs takes 2 / 3 times less than this Java/Android one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the first simple thing to try would be to ensure that your web-server is supplying a correct `ContentLength` header in the HTTP response.  Looking at some version of the source-code for HttpCore's `EntityUtils` class, we see that if this information is not available, it defaults to using a `CharArrayBuffer` of just 4k, buffering 1k of data when writing.  On the 4th, 5th, and subsequent writes to the `CharArrayBuffer` (all the way up to 500, you say), it gradually increments the buffer by 1k ... using `System.arrayCopy()`.   Yuck.  There's your performance misery right there.

If speed is really important to you however, you'll avoid using `EntityUtils` entirely.  It's just not responsible to turn a stream into a temporary 500k `String` ... especially on a phone!  You'll need to find or write a `Base64DecodingInputStream` or `Base64DecodingReader` to wrap your `InputStream` from `response.getEntity().getContent()`, and feed that ... instead of a `String` ... to your parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your exhaustive explanation !